# Rotating on x axis causes rotation on y and z as well

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate an object in it's x-axis based on the movement of my VR hand. It works well on Y-axis with `rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, rot.eulerAngles.y, 0);` but when I try to rotate it in X-axis with `rot = Quaternion.Euler (rot.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0);`, it rotates in all 3 axes.

Why does rotating on X axis causes rotation on Y and Z and how do I fix it?

```
    [Header ("arrow")]
    public GameObject arrow;

    [Header ("Hand")]
    public GameObject hand;

    [Header ("Activation Settings")]
    public float activationDistance = 0.5f;

    private Quaternion currentRot;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private bool offsetSet;


    private void Start () {
        offsetSet = false;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (IsCloseEnough ()) {
            Rotate ();
        } else {
            offsetSet = false;
        }

    }

    void SetOffsets () {
        if (offsetSet)
            return;

        startPos = Vector3.Normalize (hand.transform.position - arrow.transform.position);
        currentRot = arrow.transform.rotation;

        offsetSet = true;
    }

    void Rotate () {
        SetOffsets ();

        Vector3 closestPoint = Vector3.Normalize (hand.transform.position - arrow.transform.position);
        var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation (startPos, closestPoint);
        rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, rot.eulerAngles.y, 0); //Problem is here
        arrow.transform.rotation = rot * currentRot;

    }

    bool IsCloseEnough () {
        if (Mathf.Abs (Vector3.Distance (hand.transform.position, arrow.transform.position)) < activationDistance)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: please look into this https://answers.unity.com/questions/1721294/how-to-rotate-object-bases-on-another-rotation.html

Comment: _When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned._